# Axes zoom effect in 3D plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I get a zoom in effect on one of the axis, for a 3D plot in python. Something like in the figure below, but I would need to zoom in in one of the axis (say x) of a 3D plot. I couldn't find anything online and I don't really have any idea how to code this from scratch. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: [Axes Zoom Effect](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_zoom_effect.html?highlight=zoom) Kindly refer to this.

Comment: @r-beginners thanks! Can this be done for a 3D plot, too? I see that they use the zoom box as a subplot. Can I have subplots some being 3D some being 2D?

Comment: I don't know any more than that.